# Почему owl не видит itemы в функции?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Добрый день есть такой код

```
var storiesItems = $('.stories-items');

  storiesItems.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    onInitialize: callback
  })

  function callback(event){
    var items  = event;
    console.log(items)
```

Вывод в консоле 0. При том что слайдер работает именно отсюда и у него 4 элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код выводит корневой элемент карусели.
Чтобы можно было узнать число элементов, нужно поискать внутри. Предлагаю такое решение:

```js
var storiesItems = $('.stories-items');

  storiesItems.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    onInitialize: callback
  })

  function callback(event){
    var items  = event.target;
    console.log($(items).find('.item').length)
   }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.stories-items .item {
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.owl-stage {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="stories-items">
  <div class="item">
    <div>item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```